# javac complie with jar file

Tags: java, compiler-errors, command, command-line-interface

> it is my dir structrue

```
compile_java
├── my_lib
│   ├── bin
│   │   ├── pak1
│   │   │   └── A.class
│   │   └── pak2
│   │       └── B.class
│   ├── dist
│   │   └── my_lib.jar
│   └── src
│       ├── pak1
│       │   └── A.java
│       └── pak2
│           └── B.java
└── using_lib
    ├── bin
    └── src
        └── main
            └── Main.java
```

> it is A.java source code and Main.java source code

```
package pak1;

public class A {
    public void method(){
        System.out.println("A method executed");
    }
}
```

---

```
package main;

import pak1.*;
import pak2.*;
public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                A a = new A();
                a.method();

                B b = new B();
                b.method();
        }
}
```

> first i made jar file through this command

compile_java$ jar cvf my_lib/dist/my_lib.jar my_lib/bin/pak1/A.class my_lib/bin/pak2/B.class

> second i try compile Main.java throuth this command

```
javac -d using_lib/bin/ -cp my_lib/dist/*.jar using_lib/src/main/Main.java
```

> but it is error like this

```
using_lib/src/main/Main.java:3: error: package pak1 does not exist
import pak1.*;
^
using_lib/src/main/Main.java:4: error: package pak2 does not exist
import pak2.*;
^
using_lib/src/main/Main.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
                A a = new A();
                ^
  symbol:   class A
  location: class Main
using_lib/src/main/Main.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
                A a = new A();
                          ^
  symbol:   class A
  location: class Main
using_lib/src/main/Main.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
                B b = new B();
                ^
  symbol:   class B
  location: class Main
using_lib/src/main/Main.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
                B b = new B();
                          ^
  symbol:   class B
  location: class Main
6 errors
```

Comment: Check your .jar file for directory structure(you can simply unzip it). If you packed it with the command mentioned above, it is more than likely, that your directory structure within the jar starts with "bin". therefore the compiler can't find the package. Try to pack the jar with the -C option instead of specifying the files separately to avoid this. for example 'jar -cf test.jar -C bin/ .'(the dot at the end is no mistake) . furthermore try to call javac like this: 'javac -cp ".:pathtojar.jar" -d outputdir pathtojavafile'

Comment: Personally I wouldn't have multiple output bin directories. It only causes confusion and the contents are transient anyway. That said, the following works fine for me: `goose@t410:/tmp/compile_java$ javac -d bin -cp my_lib/dist/my_lib.jar ./using_lib/src/main/*.java ./my_lib/pak1/*.java ./my_lib/pak2/*.java`

Comment: True - well spotted ;)

Comment: that's what I meant with my first comment...

Comment: @roediGERhard *it is more than likely, that your directory structure within the jar starts with "bin".* Actually no. They will start, with my_lib. The correct command would be `jar cvf my_lib/dist/my_lib.jar -C my_lib/bin pak1/A.class pak2/B.class`

Comment: Tomatoes, tomatoes. Bin, mylib, my_lib doesn't matter. In the end it most likely does not start with the package name, which is required to work properly. Furthermore I question the practice of naming every class separately, but whatever floats your boat.

Comment: It *does* matter, since the OP needs to know how to use `jar` properly and how the paths work. You're right in the sense that one wrong entry is as wrong as another wrong entry though